# How to manually encrypt and decrypt user credentials using machine key

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-membership

I am working on android app for a web application software built in asp.net 4.0 VB.Net.Problem is that I have to create web services for user authentication and authorisation but web application module is using asp.net built in membership module for user authentication and authorisation. Login in web application is done like this:

```
 Dim objDsLoginDetails As DataSet
        ' Dim boolBrowser As Boolean
        Dim objLoginBl As LoginBL
        Dim strConnectionString As String

        Try

            Dim validateUser As Boolean = False

            strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("HighriseeSiteWebConnectionString").ToString
            objLoginBl = New LoginBL(strConnectionString)
            Dim u As MembershipUser = Membership.GetUser(txtusername.Text.Trim)
            validateUser = Membership.ValidateUser(txtusername.Text.Trim, txtpassword.Text.Trim)
            If validateUser = False Then
                'Lblerror.Text = Constants.errmsg_LOGIN_ERROR
                'Trace.Warn("Login failed")
                'Exit Sub
            End If
            Dim Role As String()
            Dim RoleId As Guid

            Role = Roles.GetRolesForUser(txtusername.Text.Trim)
            RoleId = Services.GetRoleIdForUser(Role(0).ToString)
            If Role.Length = 0 Then
                Lblerror.Text = Constants.errmsg_LOGIN_ERROR
                Exit Sub
            End If

               :
               :
               :
```

Now I tried to handle login operation manually using encryptions in web method like this:

```
  <System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
    Public Function encryptPass()
        Dim plaintextValue As String = "admin123$"

        Dim plaintextBytes As Object = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plaintextValue)


        Dim s As String = MachineKey.Encode(plaintextBytes, MachineKeyProtection.Encryption)





        Return s
    End Function
```

but issue is encrypted password stored automatically by asp.net membership is like this:

```
enOtcqBeiXhWaIDNJX8YBFF+UHf8vpdHmLsyBukE3F6480hDPIypRD8eqdLV1pXN
```

and password encrypted by encryptPass() function which I am trying to do manually is encrypts like this:

```
     7A326D74C7921A853534D42140E150AA
```

So my question is how can I encrypt and decrypt manually using machine key from web.config and result should be same as comes with asp.net membership module.Also if there is any better approach to do this plz let me know.Thanks